# I can't decode a video using DCPM losslessly

Tags: python, opencv, video, encoding, decode

I am trying to encode and decode a video losslessly using the DCPM technique which states that you send the first frame of a video as it is and then you calculate the difference to the next frame as `currentFrame - previousFrame` and you send this sequence until the video has been fully encoded. In the first file I do this and it seems to work fine.

Now when I try to decode, I display the first frame and then compute `firstFrame + nextFrame' and display this sequence until the end which should result in the real video since the first frame is sent intact and the next one is the difference between the second frame and the first frame. But as I do this process I get a bunch of noise and the video isn't decoded losselessly. Why is that?

Below is the encoder

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
previous_frame = None

video_codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

# Setup the output
output = cv2.VideoWriter('dpcm_encoded_video.avi', video_codec, int(video.get(5)),
(int(video.get(3)), int(video.get(4))), False)

if not video.isOpened():
    print("Error while trying to play the video.")
i = 0
while video.isOpened():
    not_exception, current_frame = video.read()
    if not_exception:
        if previous_frame is None:  # First iteration
            current_frame = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            previous_frame = current_frame
            output.write(current_frame)
            continue
        if i <= 217: #Video is 217 frames
            current_frame = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            i += 1

        difference = current_frame - previous_frame
        cv2.imshow('Error frames', difference)
        output.write(difference)
        previous_frame = current_frame

        if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the decoder

```
import cv2
# Load video
video = cv2.VideoCapture('dpcm_encoded_video.avi')

# Load the first frame of the video
success, first_frame = video.read()
first_frame = cv2.cvtColor(first_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Set video codec
video_codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

# Setup the output
output = cv2.VideoWriter('dpcm_decoded_video.avi', video_codec, int(video.get(5)), (int(video.get(3)), int(video.get(4))), False)
output.write(first_frame)

frame_num = 0

previous_frame = first_frame

while video.isOpened():
    # Skip the first frame because we load it outside the loop
    if frame_num == 0:
        #success, current_frame = video.read()
        frame_num += 1
        continue

    success, current_frame = video.read()
    frame_num += 1

    if not success:
        break

    # Frame to BW
    current_frame = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Sum frames
    current_frame = previous_frame + current_frame

    previous_frame = current_frame
    output.write(current_frame)

video.release()
output.release()
```

Comment: video_in = cv2.VideoCapture(video_in)
width = int(video_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(video_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
length = int(video_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
video_out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_out, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 20.0, (width, height)

Comment: you forget that integers can overflow/underflow and then wrap around. your code contains nothing that takes care to receive **signed** differences

Comment: My code worked just fine, the problem is that i used the codec XVID which is not lossless. After changing to a lossless codec it worked just fine!